# Ajax Modal Popup doesnt show inline validation on top of popup rather it shows it behind the modal popup

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

When i use use  following inline jQuery Based validation in asp.net c# web form show on the link below it works fine.
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/01/jquery-beautiful-popup-form-validations.html

But when i try to use the same in Ajax Modal Popup then it shows the validation behind the Modal popup as show in the screen shot. [image: Screen shot of how it looks]

It validates all input fields but show the validation behind the popup as indicated by red arrows in the image. I am not able to find the right CSS property so that it can show inline validation on top of popup.

I am using same css and jquery files shown on the link i have only modified the color property of the css to show inline background in golden color rest is all same

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/01/jquery-beautiful-popup-form-validations.html

I am sure someone must have encountered similar problem and fixed it, Any help from CSS gurus or anyone who can help to sort this issue, i have tried but i am not good with CSS.

my .aspx page code

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpShowCommentPopUp" runat="server" TargetControlID="lnkBtnComment" PopupControlID="pnlComment"
 BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>

<asp:Panel ID="pnlComment" runat="server" BackColor="White" Height="500px" Width="500px" style="display:none">
<div id="commentForm">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updPnlComment" runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>

<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600px">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10">
                    <tr>
                        <td  colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="lblPostComment" runat="server" Text="Post Comment"  CssClass="lblPostComment"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td  colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="lblCommentMsg"  CssClass="txtLabelComment" runat="server" Text="Please make sure your comment is not abusive, defamatory or offensive. All 
                            fields must be filled in correctly or the comment will not be approved."></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="lblRequired" CssClass="txtLabelComment" runat="server" Text="[*] indicates a required field."></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="100px">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" Text="Full Name" CssClass="txtLabelComment"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFullName" runat="server" CssClass="validate[required] txtbox300Comment"></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;*
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text="Email Address" CssClass="txtLabelComment"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" CssClass="validate[required,custom[email]] txtbox300Comment"></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;*
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text="Country" CssClass="txtLabelComment"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddCountry" runat="server" CssClass="validate[required] ddGeneralComment">
    <asp:ListItem Value="" ></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AF">Afghanistan</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AL">Albania</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="DZ">Algeria</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AS">American Samoa</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AD">Andorra</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AO">Angola</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
                            &nbsp;*</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >
                            <asp:Label ID="lblMSG" runat="server" Text="Your Message" CssClass="txtLabelComment"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessage" runat="server" CssClass="validate[required, maxSize[500]] txtbox300MComment" 
                                TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="10"></asp:TextBox>
                            &nbsp;*</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td  valign="top" >                            
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCapcha" runat="server" Text="Verification Code" CssClass="txtLabelComment"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" >
                        <uc1:MyCaptcha ID="MyCaptcha1" runat="server"  />

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td >&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbAnonymous" runat="server" 
                                Text="I wish to be anonymous. Do not publish my name with my comment. " 
                                CssClass="txtLabelComment" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td > &nbsp;</td>
                        <td>  
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSaveComments" runat="server" onclick="btnSaveComments_Click" 
                                Text="Post Comment" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td > &nbsp;</td>
                        <td>  
                            &nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

 </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

**CSS File**

```
.inputContainer {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.formError {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 300px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 5000;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ajaxSubmit {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #55ea55;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    display: none
}

.formError .formErrorContent {
    width: 100%;
    background: #b4984e;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5001;
    color: #fff;
    width: 150px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}

.greenPopup .formErrorContent {
    background: #33be40;
}

.blackPopup .formErrorContent {
    background: #393939;
    color: #FFF;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow {
    width: 15px;
    margin: -2px 0 0 13px;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 5006;
}
body[dir='rtl'] .formError .formErrorArrow,
body.rtl .formError .formErrorArrow {
    margin: -2px 13px 0 0;
}

.formError .formErrorArrowBottom {
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    margin: 0px 0 0 12px;
  top:2px;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow div {
    border-left: 2px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 2px solid #ddd;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #444;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px #444;
    font-size: 0px;
    height: 1px;
    background: #b4984e;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    display: block;
}

.formError .formErrorArrowBottom div {
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

.greenPopup .formErrorArrow div {
    background: #33be40;
}

.blackPopup .formErrorArrow div {
    background: #393939;
    color: #FFF;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .line10 {
    width: 15px;
    border: none;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .line9 {
    width: 13px;
    border: none;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .line8 {
    width: 11px;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .line7 {
    width: 9px;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .line6 {
    width: 7px;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .line5 {
    width: 5px;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .line4 {
    width: 3px;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .line3 {
    width: 1px;
    border-left: 2px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 2px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 0 solid #ddd;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .line2 {
    width: 3px;
    border: none;
    background: #ddd;
}

.formError .formErrorArrow .line1 {
    width: 1px;
    border: none;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: Can you post any of your markup? The generated HTML/CSS from that screenshot would really help here.

Comment: I have posted HTML and main css used my the inline validation jQuery. Another example of how code works on this link http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/demos/demoValidators.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is mostly `z-index` problem. The overlay which you are using must be having higher `z-index` than those error info contianers. Try to find out the `css` for error info containers in your project and set some max `z-index` and try.

Comment: I can find z-index property as also show in teh example code what should i change it to it is set to 5000 at one place and second place it is set to 5001

Comment: changing z-index property to 9999 bought it up on top of grey shade but it is behind the popup. I mean now it is in between the grey shade and popup

Comment: This is not adviceable but try adding one more 9.

Comment: I got it right now AjaxModal popup uses z-index=100001;  and i made property of my inline validation shows higher that Ajax Madal popup z-index=199991;